# Javascript load slow in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a live currency price ticker in my HTML page with javascript.
But after I open the page it takes 5-9 Seconds that the price shows up.

Can I make it faster? I also have a page loader but I think js doesn't load with it.

Here the html code:

```
    <div class="hold2">
  <span id="btc1">1 BTC = </span><br>
  <span id="cost">＿＿</span> <span id="currency">USD</span>
  <br> <br>
    <span id="btc1">1 BTC = </span><br>
  <span id="cost2">＿＿</span> <span id="currency">EUR</span>
<br> <br>
    <span id="btc1">1 BTC = </span>  <br>
  <span id="cost3">＿＿</span> <span id="currency">GBP</span>
</div>
    <script src="Bitcoinprice/js/index.js"></script>
```

js code:

```
var update = function () {
  $.getJSON('https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/all', function (data) {
    $("#cost").html(Math.floor(data.USD.last * 100) / 100);
    $("#cost2").html(Math.floor(data.EUR.last * 100) / 100);
    $("#cost3").html(Math.floor(data.GBP.last * 100) / 100);
 });
};

var updater = setInterval(update, 10000);
update();
```

Comment: It cannot be reproduced with your given code, it shows up instantly on this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ogd35vzb/). How long does it take to load `https://api.bitcoinaverage.com/ticker/all`  if you open this link directly in the browser? Beside that you should look into the network tab of your browser to check if there is a script that takes long to load and blocks all other scripts.

Comment: If i open the url in my browser it loads instantly. I checked the network tab and within the page loader they are 100 requests and 10 after i see the page.With cache it loads in 2 seconds. But i can not find other files they are loads long. All is writen with Bootstrap.

Comment: The only solution to make it instant is to get the initial data on the server side. Do you have a problem with that?

Comment: @OmarAlshaker link shows up instantly in the browser for the OP, then the slow loading its most likely not related to the given code. It is more likely that the server of the OP is slow or another 3rd party script. So saving the data on the server would not solve the problem.

Comment: Good point. Perhaps throwing the attached code inside the HTML and not loading it separately would be smarter. i.e. lose the `<script src="Bitcoinprice/js/index.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks guys! I have added the js now to the php file and set the "var updater = setInterval" to 10 and now load it instant.Solved! its not the best solution but it workes now;)